# Eclipse Oxygen: how to specify module dependencies

Tags: java, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I am trying to familiarize myself with Eclipse's support for Java 9 modules.  I use Eclipse Oxygen with the Java 9 Support Package from the marketplace and the latest JDK 9 u180.

The problem concerns module dependencies and how to let Eclipse know about them.

My understanding is that in Eclipse a JPMS module corresponds to an Eclipse project. I created three projects aka modules and added the necessary module-info files:

```
module com.effjava.app {
  requires com.effjava.support;
}

module com.effjava.support {
  exports com.effjava.support.hlp;
  exports com.effjava.support.test;
  exports com.effjava.support.user;

  requires transitive com.effjava.util;
}

module com.effjava.util {
  exports com.effjava.util.cbk;
  exports com.effjava.util.reg;
}
```

It is a simple top-down dependency chain.  The module descriptors are correct; I already succeeded in setting up the same modules in IntelliJ.

My problem is:  how do I tell Eclipse that the top modules depend on the bottom ones, e.g. that the middle module `com.effjava.support` depends on the bottom module `com.effjava.util`?

I did specify the dependency in the module-info file (via `requires transitive`) and Eclipse accepts the directive without a complaint.  Yet I see an error message when I compile the middle module `com.effjava.support`.  The error message says that a public type from package `com.effjava.util.cbk` is not visible, despite being exported by module `com.effjava.util` and required by `module com.effjava.support`.

[screenshot showing project structure and compiler error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCWtS.jpg)

In order to specify the dependency, I exported the content of the bottom module `com.effjava.util` to a jar file, including the module-info.class.  Hence it is a modular jar file.

Then I imported the modular jar file into the `com.effjava.support` module and added the imported modular jar file to the build path.  To no avail.

[image: screenshot of build path]

I tried it without an import, just adding the modular jar as an external library.  It didn't work either.

The question is:  how do I correctly specify module dependencies in Eclipse?

Comment: The details of this are still work in progress. For now it's probably best to let your Projects explicitly depend on each other via `Java Build Path > Projects` (this is partly redundant with module-info, but since modules are not versioned you probably need a build system to manage your dependencies anyway). OTOH, the errors in your screenshot look bogus. If this happens with latest from the marketplace (1.1.1.v20170731-0938_BETA_JAVA9) please file a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT&component=Core